# Error in app.js file of Node Application

Tags: node.js

I try to run this simple code but I can't find the desire output.

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path')
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    session = require('express-session');
    
    
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname , 'views'));

  
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
  
  
  
  var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
  
  if(env === 'development'){
      // dev specific settings
    
       
  } else {
      //Production specific settings
      
    
  }
  

  require('./routes/routes.js')(express,app);
   
 
  app.listen (3000 , function(){
    
    console.log('Mode:'+ env);
 });
```

RUN ON Window CMD : > set NODE_ENV = develoment

> node app.js

```
                > Mode : development
```

but when -

RUN ON Window CMD : > set NODE_ENV = production

> node app.js

```
                > Mode : development // again same thing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spaces around equals sign `set NODE_ENV=production` 
 or try running the code like this `NODE_ENV=production node app.js`

Comment: Can you explain why this happen with Space ??

Comment: It's just a way the system variable assignment works. Everything after equals sign is treated as a value of the variable. The same thing applies to OSX and Linux systems

Comment: it expect space as parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this Using console log verify your output.
Remove spaces around equals sign set NODE_ENV=production 
or try running the code like this NODE_ENV=production node app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path')
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    session = require('express-session');


 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname , 'views'));


  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));



  var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

  if(env == 'development'){
      // dev specific settings
      console.log("Development");

  } else {
      //Production specific settings
      conosole.log("Production");

  }



  require('./routes/routes.js')(express,app);   

  app.listen (3000 , function(){

    console.log('Mode:'+ env);
 });
```